# Swift UIKIt How to Adjust ScrollView Dynamically Based Data

Tags: swift, uikit

I've created a page that contains data from API. I want to make this page scrollable so all the content can appear in my app. But, when I tried to use storyboard with ScrollView, the page isn't scrollable. Here is my storyboard

[image]

The whole content is not appear :

[image]

How can I fix this page so I can scroll my page and show all of my content from API?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I think you've added the scrollView incorrectly, following steps are working fine for me:*

**Step 1:**
Add scroll view to the main view controller and set its all constraints to safe-area:

[image]

**Step 2:**
Select the scroll view and uncheck/disable `Content Layout Guides`:

[image]

**Step 3:**
Add a UIView inside the scroll view; It will be used as a container view:

[image]

**Step 4:**
Set uiview's constraints to its superview (scroll view):

[image]

Like this:
[image]

**Step 5:**
Add uiview's height and width equal to its superview (scroll view):

[image]

**Step 6:**
Select the uiview's height constraint and change its priority to 250:

[image]

**Step 7:**
You're done! now it's time to add your content (for example, UILabel here) into the UIView (container view):

[image]